# Can't get OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime to open 'minecraft.jar' file

Tags: java, openjdk

I have 64bit Ubuntu 12.10 installed with an Intel® Core™ i5-3570K CPU. I use Chromium. I have installed OpenJDK 7 but whenever I right-click the `.jar` file and click "*open with openjdk java 7 runtime*" nothing happens at all. I have tried this with OpenJDK 6 and nothing happens.

Could it be a 64bit conflict? I have also tried a different `minecraft.jar` and nothing changed. The `.jar` is set to executable.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting it from the terminal instead using this method:

Open the terminal again Applications > Accessories > Terminal Enter the following commands, substituting 'minecraft_server' with the name of the folder you extracted the server to:

```
cd minecraft_server
java -Xms1G -Xmx1G -jar minecraft.jar nogui
```

Taken from http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server#Ubuntu

Comment: I don't understand 'substituting 'minecraft_server' with the name of the folder you extracted the server to:' i just have a file called minecraft.jar in my downloads folder :L

Comment: Replace minecraft_server.jar with minecraft.jar.  and the downloads folder is at /home/(ur username)/downloads"

Answer (score 0):

Use the OpenJDK Java 6 runtime, not the Java 7 runtime. In Nautilus (the file manager), right-click on the file, go to Properties > Permissions, and click the checkbox to *allow executing the file as a program*.

Comment: Why OpenJDK 6 instead of 7?